# Proguard obfuscates class despite -keepclasseswithmembernames

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

I try to prevent obfuscation for the classes which contains attribute
@com.evernote.android.state.State on any members

For this i add to my rule:

```
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * { @com.evernote.android.state.State *;}
```

And it doesn't work. Classes are obfuscated

But if specify more concrete condition:

```
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * { @com.evernote.android.state.State <fields>;}
```

It works fine!

Can somebody clarify why first variant doesn't work?

Build-gradle version is 3.1.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule `-keepclasseswithmembernames` will match only if *all* specified members match. If you use a wildcard like `*`, then all fields and methods must be annotated, which is probably not the case.

If you match only fields then it will work.